# Creating independent variable Stata in Panel Data model

Tags: excel, stata

*Data and description of variables*

[Picture 1 and Sample unbalanced paneldata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZh7i.png)

- Picture 1 shows a balanced panel data that I have created using an unbalanced  one provided as a sample in the same image, where I had multiple products (ID) for different amount of years (YEAR). For each product, there were a different number of Shops offering the given product (ID). So as stated, this is a balanced set created by sorting out for the same years, same products (ID), and same shops (marked by the orange area in the sample unbalanced paneldata). This is an important assumption that might affect the perception of the issue stated below. **The following is therefore a description of the table shown in Picture 1:**
- Years indicates the amount of period a product lasts for a given product (ID)
- Shop 1, Shop 2, Shop 3 indicate different prices for a given product (ID) by different firms
- The minimum and second minimum value depict what shops for a given year and product (ID), have the lowest and second lowest price for that given year. This is needed to calculate the Price difference, which is **(Second minimum value - Minimum Value) / (Minimum Value)
- An example of this, is given for row 5 (Year 01.01.1995 - ID 101) where Price difference would be (3999-3790)/3790 = 5,51% (In **Picture 1)**

*Issue*

- In my balanced panel data, (**Picture 1)**, I want to run a fixed effect regression in STATA using xtreg function, where the dependent variable is the Price difference, and number of shops selling a product  are the independent variables. This is, so I can say how Price difference as a dependent variable is affected when there is 1 shop selling, when there are two shops selling, and when there are three shops selling.
- Another problem is, is my assumption valid at all of creating a balanced panel? Is it correct to create a balanced from the unbalanced paneldata, or must I use the unbalanced panel to create such a variable?
- So my main issue is how to create such independent variables, that measure the dimension of number of shops offering products.  To
  clarify what I mean, I have included an example of a sample fixed
  effect regression that may explain the structure that I attempt to
  seek, in **Picture 2** below:

**NOTE** (In **picture 2** expected cell mean to the right is the same as Price difference in Picture 1, and is used as dependent variable. They are regressed on number of firms/shops as independent variables, and these I have an issue creating)

[**Picture 2**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwIFp.png)

*What I have tried*

- I have tried, using dummy variables, on shops, but they ended up getting dropped. The dataset provided in picture 1 is a balanced data set as mentioned, which is needed to run (I assume) a fixed effect regression on a paneldata.

*End remark*

I stated this question earlier in a much more imprecise manner, where I apologiese for any inconvenience. The problem I think, might be that either I have set it up wrong in excel, hence the dummy's are dropped, or something of that nature. It might also be, that I have to use the unbalanced set in order to create this independent variable, so that might also be a problem, that I am attempting to use a balanced set instead of the unbalanced one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your unbalanced sample (as we discussed in the comments, the balanced sample will not make sense) we first need to create a variable for the number of shops offering each ID, let us say we have the same data as in the top portion of your Picture 1

```
egen number_of_firms = rownonmiss(Shop*)
xtset ID year // to use xtreg, we must tell Stata the data are panel
xtreg Price_difference i.number_of_firms
```

The `xtreg` is the regression shown in your Picture 2.

If you want the number of firms variable to be formatted a bit more like Picture 2, you can do something like this:

```
qui levelsof number_of_firms, local(num)
foreach n in `num' {
    local lab_def `lab_def' `n' "`n' Firms"

}
label def num_firms `lab_def'
label values number_of_firms num_firms
label var number_of_firms "Number of Firms"
```

And then run the regression and the output will be formatted with the number of firms lables.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the reply. I have added several new information, in attempt to clarify the nature of the question, so that one may understand it better. Because this answer was provided before the editing, should I not run it on existing price variables? Why does one have to generate random ones? Thanks.

Comment: I think I am still a bit unclear about your question. The balanced panel you create will have each product being sold by 3 firms in all years, so the number of firms will always be 3, and won't give any useful information. do you want your regression to look like: `reg Price_difference number_of_firms i.ID`? Additionally, I put that example because you did not provide any data for me to use, so I created my own (some people on the forum are picky about this and will tell you to use `ssc install dataex` so that you can share your data)

Comment: Ah, splendid, yes that is exactly how the regression should look, then it makes good sense that I cant run it on the balanced set. Lets say I want to run it on the unbalanced panel data example then with shops 1-7 to capture the variation, would it still look as you provided in the example? (Thanks again)

Comment: I have updated the answer, I made a small mistake in my comment above, it should be `i.number_of_firms` so that we get a separate coefficient for each separate value of that variable. This is also fixed in the answer above.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks a lot. Also, as a small follow up question I was wondering, what type of method in panel data (or how) or statistics in general, would you see fit to capture the nature of when this price gap occurs over time? By this I mean, if we look at the unbalanced panel data, we see that price gap occurs when the number of shops which offer the product at the minimum price is 1. When the number of firms offering at minimum price is more than 1, price dispersion ceases to exist, so how would one explain this pattern in a panel data with regards to variation across shops and across time?

Comment: Maybe one thing you can do is look into tobit regression (becasue your data are bounded at 0) but I am not sure exactly what you're asking. This question would probably be better answered on Statalist than by me alone

Comment: Ah perfect, I tried the tobit regression and it works nicely. Another small followup I am not sure about, is that I want to run fixed effects as follows: xtset ID Year  --> xtreg Price_difference i.number_of_firms i.ID, fe
However, I get omitted due to co-linearity on all the ID's. But I know that articles, for example on page 32
[http://sandcat.middlebury.edu/econ/repec/mdl/ancoec/0710.pdf] , they add for fixed effects using the product as PRODit on price gap, which is the same as ID in my example. However I think I might have set it up wrong, because it keeps getting omitted.

Comment: so the `, fe` portion of your code is already doing the i.ID and not showing you. the `fe` option uses the panelvar as fixed effects, so you can omit the `i.ID` part of the code or omit the `fe` part and I believe you should get the same results.

Comment: Ah, interesting indeed. The funny thing is also that when I do for example regress Price_difference i.number_of_firms i.ID i get a much higher R^2 (like 35%), vs 2% with the xtreg Price_difference i.number_of_firms, fe. But thanks a lot for all the input!

Comment: I believe that is because `fe` adjusts the R2 because you're using a bunch of dummy variables whereas `i.ID` does not adjust, but I am not certain and it could be worth looking up if it impacts your analysis

Comment: You were right indeed, I double checked it. Another small thing im wondering about, is, would it be considered an over specification, if one adds both number_of_firms and i.number_of_firms as independent variables? Or even number_of_firms, its square and i.number_of_firms, all as independent variable in the same model? What I mean is, can one add a continuous variable (number_of_firms) , its dummies on different levels, and its squares, all as independent variables for the same independent variable (here number_of_firms) ? Thanks again by the way. This is just something I was curious of.

Comment: The worry is perfect multicollienarity, you could not do i.number_of_firms and number_of_firms because the sum of all of the dummy variables for i.number_of_firms equals the number_of_firms variable. You could do i.number_of_firms and number_of_firms^2 but the interpretation of the coefficients would be a bit weird. You could also do number_of_firms and number_of_firms^2 where the interpretation is more clear and that is pretty normal. This question might be worth asking on Statalist or Stats stack exchange to see what experts say.